# What's the best practice around exporting an async value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async-await

In the code snippet below, I'm trying to export a value that relies on async operations. Is this the best way to do that? It just feels a bit weird.

I'd love any suggestions! Thanks!

```js
import ohm from "ohm-js";

export default await (async () => {
  let response = await fetch("./grammar.ohm");
  let source = await response.text();
  return ohm.grammar(source);
})();
```

Comment: I'm surprised that it works at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the [async IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```
import ohm from "ohm-js";

let response = await fetch("./grammar.ohm");
let source = await response.text();
export default await ohm.grammar(source);
```